# Related Product Grid

Tags: magento, grid, product

In magento admin I am creating a lookbook module which will have a list of lookbooks and each lookbook can have images and related products. I have it working to the point where I can upload the images and able to save it but can't find a way to associate products to each lookbook. I'm thinking of to load a product grid (something like related product) and I can tick the checkbox for multiple products and get them saved for each lookbook. So the question is how can I load the product grid in custom module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yo should reply the behavior of catalog product. i recomend you to understand how to work in Adminhtml/controllers/ProductController.php the indexAction when you go to url:

```
http://yourdomani.com/index.php/admin/catalog_product/index
```

this is only how to work the controller, but you shoult understand all blocks load in this extension of the core. The part of backend work diferento to the frontend, then you shoult take a time look how to work.